# How to make PropertyGrid Collection Items semi editable?

Tags: c#, propertygrid

I have a class called `BasePath`, which contains `Drive`, `Path` and `MetaName` properties.
Furthermore I have created a `BasePathCollection` to show them in the PropertyGrid (expandable).

For adding a path you have to click the "three dots button" where you get another PropertyGrid where you see all items of the "BasePathCollection" on the left and the items properties on the right.

[image]

When `BasePath` properties are `[ReadOnly(true)]` I can edit the path by clicking to another "three dots button":

[image]

But now I need to make the the `MetaName` property editable and boom, suddenly I can't edit the path. The "three dots button" is no longer accessible:

[image]

What do I need to change for getting the "three dots button" back with the ability to still edit the `MetaName` property?

Edit:
Declaration of Properties:

How is your MetaName property declared? Show us some code please. – Simon Mourier 1 hour ago

```
    private string m_metaName;

    [Browsable(true)]
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public string Drive { get { return m_drive; } set { m_drive = value; } }

    [Browsable(true)]
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public string Path { get { Clear(); return m_path; } set { m_path = value; Clear(); } }

    [Browsable(true)]
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public string MetaName { get { return m_metaName; } set { m_metaName = value; } }
```

Yes in a lack of knowledge I tried to set the following attributes for the BasePath-Class to make it editable.

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(BasePathConverter))]
[Editor(typeof(FolderNameEditorWithRootFolder), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
public class BasePath : IComparable<BasePath>{ ... }
```

Comment: How is your MetaName property declared? Show us some code please.

Comment: In the question please, not in comments!

Comment: There must be something else in your basepath class, by default with a standard class, there is no '...' button in the Value line.

Comment: Ok so you have a custom UITypeEditor "FolderNameEditorWithRootFolder" on this class. You need to add a similar (but probably not the same since it doesn't work on the same thing) custom UITypeEditor on the MetaName property.

Comment: OK, but my major problem is that I cant change the actual path (Drive and path) with the "...". Nevertheless if I can edit the MetaName.
The Path should be editable over such "...". Btw. is it possible to change the "Path" and "Drive" properties via changing the "MetaName" over a "Editor"?

Comment: Yes, like I say, you need a custom UITypeEditor. Such an editor will get a reference to an ITypeDescriptorContext object that contains the current instance reference (ITypeDescriptorContext.Instance) from which you can get access to all properties.